# Length Of File (LOF) returns 0

Tags: file, vb6

LOF returns 0.

Here is the file

[image]

Here is a sample function

```
Public Function GetNumberOfLinesInFile(ByVal FileFullQualifiedName As String) As Double
Dim f As Integer
Dim FileBytes As Double
Dim LineCount As Double

f = FreeFile(0)
Open FileFullQualifiedName For Binary Access Read As #f
FileBytes = LOF(f)
'//CODE MISSING
Close #f
GetNumberOfLinesInFile = LineCount
End Function
```

**Edit**
It looks it does not work with `Binary Access`, it is working fine if file is opened as following

```
Open FileFullQualifiedName For Input Access Read As #f
```

**Edit 2**
In the above sample function `LOF` worked by declaring `FileBytes` as `Long` but it is not working everywhere. For example in the following line, both `LOC` and `LOF` are returning `0`

```
Do Until Loc(FF) >= LOF(FF)
```

**Edit 3**

Somehow, the file path was changed and hence `Open FileFullQualifiedName For Binary Access Read As #f` was creating a new file, and obviously, `LOF` was returning `0` for this empty file

Comment: Why FileBytes  and LineCount are declared as Double ?? They need to be Long

Comment: @rags It did work by declaring as long, it means this function wont work if file size is > 2GB

Comment: @rags It is not working at all the places even though variable is declared as Long

Comment: What do you mean by 'Not working' ?

Comment: @rags Not working = returning 0

Comment: Check this link: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?478603-RESOLVED-FileLen%28%29-for-files-over-2GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My mistake**

Somehow, the file path was changed and hence `Open FileFullQualifiedName For Binary Access Read As #f` was creating a new file, and obviously, `LOF` was returning `0` for this empty file